# Adding primitives in metacircular evaluator

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp, evaluator, metacircular

I am working on the metacircular evaluator, and I'm trying to add primitive procedures. I am almost done, except I'm not sure how to add the error. Here is what I have so far:

```
(define primitive-procedures
  (list (list 'car car)
        (list 'cdr cdr)
        (list 'cons cons)
        (list 'null? null?)
        (list '+ +)
        (list '* *)
        (list '- -)
        (list '/ /)
        (list '< <)
        (list '<= <=)
        (list '= =)
        (list '>= >=)
        (list '> >)))
```

This works so far. I tried adding `(list '(error) (error "Metacircular Interpreter Aborted"))` for error, but it's obviously not working... How do I go about that?

Thanks!

Comment: You add `'(error)` but not `'(car)`. Why is that? I'm pretty sure you use `symbol?` to determine if it is a primitive and then `(symbol? '(error)) ; ==> #f`

Comment: it was given from the SICP book. I also tried implementing `'error`, but no luck.

Comment: Where in the book does it say to implement `error`? It uses `error` extensively, but I don't remember it being given as a procedure in the intepreter. If you take zero arguments `(list 'error error)` won't work withe `(error)` since it expects an argument. `(list 'error (lambda () (error "Metacircular Interpreter Aborted")))` will make the expected arity 0. .

Comment: ah! I have to put lambda! It solved the problem... Thank you so much! Please answer it so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same as with the other primitives, you just have to add it like this:

```
(list 'error error)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you advance something more, you will learn how to catch errors in the target language, without using the `error` from the source language.

This can be done using concepts like monads, current-continuation, continuation passing style, control with shift/reset, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference than with the other primitives.

```
 (define primitive-procedures
  (list (list 'car car)
        ...
        (list '> >)
        (list 'error error)))
```

As with the all the others the arity is checked in the underlying implementation. That means that you need to supply an argument eg. `(error "something bad happened")` will work from the interpreter. From the try to use `(error)` I'm guessing you are expecting to use it without an argument you need to supply a procedure that takes no arguments. Here is how I would have done that:

```
 (define (error-primitive)
   (error "Metacircular Interpreter Aborted"))

 (define primitive-procedures
  (list (list 'car car)
        ...
        (list '> >)
        (list 'error error-primitive)))
```

Now when you call `(error)` it will call the lambda and it will call `(error "Metacircular Interpreter Aborted")`. You can also just put a lambda in the `primitive-procedures` definition, but if you are doing a more data driver version of the interpreter later giving it a name will help with that since at this moment it is treated the same as `>`.